# Copy customisation - Zoho

Tags: version-control, cicd, zoho

This is regarding Zoho copy customisation.

Is there any way to prevent developers from directly making code changes in Zoho People production account? I understand that custom code are written within the deluge editor. However, for future change requests, can I allow developers to code outside of Zoho before pushing the code onto Zoho platform?